# outputting old form data array with Twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig, slim

I am programming a form. I am using a Select2 to allow the user choose multiple options in the select tag. If there is another error, I redirect the user back to the form and I keep the values the user had already either typed or chosen, so that he doesn't have to fill the whole form again.

Everything is fine in the rest on the fields, since I can retrieve the posted info by just using the `request.post('input_name')` function.

When it comes to these multiple choices selects, I know I get an array.
Somehow I know there are indeed values posted in array if I just make the following test:

```
{% if request.post('select2inputMultiple') %}
   <p>Data have been posted from select2 multiple</p>
{% endif %}
```

However, If I try to display (output) the data like this:

```
{{request.post('select2inputMultiple')}}
```

It throws the following error:
`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Array to string conversion")`
How can I access the items of that array?

Well, It looks that it is working, I am trying with a foreach function like this:

```
{% if request.post('select2inputMultiple') %}
   <p>Data have been posted from select2 multiple</p>
   {% for single in request.post('select2inputMultiple') %}
      value: {{single}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And it is outputting the data as desired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is named `select2inputMultiple[]`, `request.post('select2inputMultiple')` is an array (as the error indicates). You can't display an array on your page without an intermediary to convert it to a string. Easiest way to view the value from Twig is to use the `dump` method, which maps to `var_dump`. So you would do

```
{{ dump(request.post('select2inputMultiple')) }}
```

Assuming you have a select structure like this:

```
<select name="select2inputMultiple[]">
    {% for option in options %}
        <option value="{{ option.id }}">{{ option.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The easiest way to select those options from that array would be something like:

```
<select name="select2inputMultiple[]">
    {% for option in options %}
        <option value="{{ option.id }}"
            {% if option.id in request.post('select2inputMultiple') %}
                selected
            {% endif %}
            >{{ option.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```